# W3 Total Cache benefits without using plugin?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, cache, plugin-wptouch

W3 Total Cache isn't compatible with WPTouch.  Is there a way to get the benefits of W3 Total Cache without using the plugin?

Comment: How would you anticipate doing that?

Comment: Duplicate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already try adding all the mobile user agents to the "Rejected user agents" list in w3tc?

I use this list for this purpose (not created by me and certainly not complete but enough for my purpose):

iphone
ipod
ipad
aspen
incognito
webmate
android
dream
cupcake
froyo
blackberry9500
blackberry9520
blackberry9530
blackberry9550
blackberry9800
webos
s8000
bada

That's a common workaround that almost anyone uses to have w3tc and WPTouch working together.

****Edit**** You wild need to reformat the list to have one per line to insert it in w3tc.

Comment: What exactly does the rejected list do?

Comment: It's just used to stop mobile devices to get the page content out of w3tc cache, because to serve the content from the page cache all clients/devices have to get the same content. You'll of course loose a part of the performance boost from w3tc for your mobile clients.